# InfluxDB metrics is visible in frontend UI. How to restrict it?

Tags: influxdb, influxdb-2, flux-influxdb

We have installed the InfluxDB time series database and we would like to restrict users to access /metrics /debug/pprof/all and several other sensitive URLs which don't require login.

Can someone please suggest a way how we can restrict them apart from the actual DB monitoring UI running by default on 8086 port?

Answer (score 1):

In InfluxDB V1.x, you could try to update these configurations:

```
  pprof-enabled = true
  pprof-auth-enabled = false
  debug-pprof-enabled = false
```

More details could be found [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.8/administration/config/).

In InfluxDB V2.X (the link you shared indicates that you are probably using V2.X),
you could try following config options for controlling when the pprof endpoint was enabled:

- [Disable /debug/pprof](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.2/reference/config-options/#pprof-disabled). This endpoint provides runtime profiling
  data.

```
pprof-disabled: true
```

- [Disable /metrics.](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.2/reference/config-options/#metrics-disabled) This endpoint exposes internal InfluxDB
  metrics.

```
metrics-disabled: true
```

See more details [here](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.7/security/disable-devel/).

To be safe you could also limit access to those urls to ::1/127.0.0.1 to be sure in Nginx:

```
# suppose you have InfluxDB UI endpoint as below
location /influxdb2/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8086;
}

location /influxdb2/metrics/debug/pprof/all  {
    allow 127.0.0.1;
    allow ::1;
    deny all;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8086//metrics/debug/pprof/all ;
}

# some other urls restrictions
```

Comment: Thanks Munin. But I want to  know where the file to limit access to those URLs is present. I feel like there could be other URLs which cannot be turned of simply by setting false. So do you have any idea?

Comment: That's why I present you the Nginx solution. Nginx could be used as a proxy or filter to intercept those HTTP traffic.

Comment: I'll check how I can use Nginx to intercept InfluxDB UI server. As of now, no idea.

Comment: Okay. One more doubt. How can we provide those config options inside influxdb conf file if we have influxdb version 2? I mean I am using docker image so I am not able to find influxdb conf file inside the container of it. Any help?

Comment: Regarding the Nginx, you could try the doc: https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/ and https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/controlling-access-proxied-tcp/

Comment: In InfluxDB v2, "To customize the directory path of the configuration file, set the INFLUXD_CONFIG_PATH environment variable to your custom path." according to the doc: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/reference/config-options/#influxdb-configuration-file